# vAxis invisible in the chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

i'm new in google chart , and i'm  trying to use stacked bar chart ,
i'm new in google chart , and i'm  trying to use stacked bar chart ,

it's worked fine

but the vAxis values not showing in the chart.

any solution please,
thanks
this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
       function drawChart() {
           var options = {    
               width: 1500,
               height: 1500,
               bar: { groupWidth: "75%" },
               seriesType: 'bars',
               colors: ['#dacfcf', '#fee812'],
               legend: 'right',
               curveType: 'function',
               isStacked: true,
               hAxis: { viewWindowMode: "explicit", format: '###', viewWindow: { min: 0 } },
               vAxis: { textStyle: { fontSize: 7 }
               }    
           };          
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "GetData.asmx/GetChartDataClient",
               data: '{}',
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (r) {
                   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
                       "cols": [
                           { "label": "Nome", "type": "string" },
                           { "label": "En cours", "type": "number" },
                           { "label": "Clos", "type": "number" },
                       ]
                   });

                   data.addRows(r.d);                     
                   var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                   view.setColumns([0,
                       1, { calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) { return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 1); }, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
                       2, { calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) { return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 2); }, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
                   ]);

                   function getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
                       return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex) || null;
                   }

                   var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#chart_divclient")[0]);
                   chart.draw(view, options);
            
           });
```

Comment: are you drawing the chart in a hidden container, then showing it later? such as on a tab or something?

Comment: you can go ahead and build the chart, but wait until you show the container before drawing for the first time. not sure what you're using, but I have some examples. here is one using a [bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48563915/5090771) -- and another using [bootstrap tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558808/5090771)